# How do I create a pushdown automata or context-free grammar for this language?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I have a final exam tomorrow, and in preparation, and one of the practice problems is to create a pushdown automaton for this language.  My professor has said that it IS context-free, but I can't seem to find a grammar or PDA for it.  Can someone help me out?

$L=\{ 0^i1^{2i+2j}0^{i+j}|i, j \ge 1\}$

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this language is NOT context-free.  There was a small mixup and the problem was written incorrectly on the lecture slides.